# Fix kendo grid header

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to set a kendo grid header fixed. After a lot of internet search I cannot find what I exactly want to do.

This post on telerik doc show how to fix header on top of window : https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Layout/fixed-headers-grid

But it's not exactly what I want to do. I want the header fixed when scrolling the page on the location it is on the page load.

How can I do this ?

Comment: It is nice that you want to share a problema and a solution togheter, but you need to set the original post with the explained problem and an accepted answer with the solution.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown : Done ;)

Answer (score 2):

After hard work and insanity test I finally found how to fix this grid header. So I share it here because I think many people want to do this...

I rework the telerik tutorial a little for fix the header where you want, take in consideration if the grid has a toolbar and to be reusable :)

CSS :

```
.fixed-header {
    position: fixed;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Javascript (`'#main-header'` is the selector of my website main menu) :

```
/**
* Fix grid header
* @param {kendo.ui.Grid} grid - The grid
* @param {string} [selector] - The selector of the element which the header must be "stuck" on scrolling, by default the main menu
*/
function fixGridHeader(grid, selector) {
    var wrapper = grid.wrapper,
        toolbar = wrapper.find(".k-grid-toolbar"),
        header = wrapper.find(".k-grid-header");

    function resizeFixed() {
        var paddingRight = parseInt(header.css("padding-right"));
        header.css("width", wrapper.width() - paddingRight);
    }

    function scrollFixed(selector) {

        var offset = $(selector ? selector : '#main-header').offset().top + $(selector ? selector : '#main-header').outerHeight(),
            tableOffsetTop = wrapper.offset().top,
            top = $('#main-header').height() + (selector ? $(selector).height() : 0);

        if (offset >= tableOffsetTop) {
            header.addClass("fixed-header");
            if (toolbar.length > 0) {
                toolbar.addClass("fixed-header");
                toolbar.css({ 'top': top, width: "100%" });
                header.css({ 'top': top + toolbar.innerHeight() });
            }
            else {
                header.css({ 'top': top });
            }
        }
        else {
            header.removeClass("fixed-header");
            if (toolbar.length > 0)
                toolbar.removeClass("fixed-header");
        }

    }
    resizeFixed();
    $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
    $(window).scroll(function () { scrollFixed(selector); });
}
```

Comment: how hard this is and other reasons are one of several reasons why I would not recommend Kendo for serious projects.  Other grids do this and other tasks seemlessly

Comment: @TrevordeKoekkoek I think at this time no sane person use kendo anymore :D
JS framework like VueJs or React do things more easily and dev-friendly

Comment: @ Shadam: Kendo isn't a framework like VueJS or React.  In fact there are versions of Kendo for those libraries.  Vue and React don't come with any built-in grid with these functionalities.  That said I prefer other libraries like developer express or Syncfusion with better grids whether you are using React, Vue or Angular or some other Javascript framework.

Comment: @TrevordeKoekkoek You should try vuetify in this case ;)